# gstreamer with openCV in rpi4

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to build software using GStreamer and OpenCV in C++ in rpi4. But the problem is I don't have the root access so I am not able to install any packages for GStreamer. What I am trying is to copy all the libs for GStreamer and then try to build my software. I am using the following code:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("videotestsrc ! appsink",CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

But it is not working. I have tried the same with my laptop after installing GStreamer and it is working. So my guess is the problem is that the GStreamer is not setup correctly. Is there any way to use GStreamer without installing the packages by just copying the libs and bin files?

Thanks in advance.

Didn't get any solution till now.

Comment: "But the problem is I don't have the root access" give up then. You won't install a kernel driver without root access.

Comment: So, are you saying it's not possible? @Blindy

Comment: You can try to build gstreamer from source (https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer) and link to the build artifacts - no need for root privileges. (If you have the build dependencies, that is!)

Comment: Copying the files would in theory also work but you need to know what files your gstreamer pipeline then depends on. Also your raspberry is arm arch, and your laptop is probably x86.

Comment: Also, if the filesystem is not encrypted another option would be to just modify the filesystem in a [live system to get sudo rights.](https://superuser.com/a/380854/617158)

Comment: The software will be used in other RPi's which don't have root access too. So need a mechanism that doesn't need root privilege.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have root access, then there's not much you can do here. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to build them yourself for PI (if technically feasible), find somebody who has done it, or possibly use Android OS on your Pi.

FYI, [link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/) to prebuilt packages (only osx, windows, android, ios) and [link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-cerbero.html?gi-language=c#crosscompilation-of-gstreamer) to using Cerbero for building gstreamer (same deal)

Comment: I don't see any methods for RPi